Python + ChromeDriver が昨日まで正常に動作していたが、エラーが出るようになった
以下のコードでエラーが出てしまいます。
コード:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

エラーメッセージ:
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 は有効な Win32 アプリケーションではありません。

ChromeとChromeDriverのバージョンを手動で最新のものをダウンロードして、Pythonが64ビット版と出たので、64ビットをダウンロードし直しました。
それでもまだ同じエラーが出てしまいます。
どうしたら良いでしょうか？よろしくい願いいたします。

コードやエラーはこれですべてでしょうか？ / 念のため、"最新" ではなく Python や ChromeDriver 等の正確なバージョン情報も質問に含めておいた方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

書いてあるコードと「ChromeとChromeDriverのバージョンを手動で最新のものをダウンロードして」が結びつかないのですがどういうことでしょうか。書いてあるコードで動かなかったから、「手動で最新のものをダウンロードして」そちらを使うコードを書いて、でもやっぱりダメだった、という話ですか? あとTracebackは全部書いた方がよいと思います

ちょうどこんな記事があるようですが。webdriver_manager を利用して webdriver を取得しようとすると OSError が発生する現象の回避策 解決方法としてはwebdriver_managerではなく最新版のseleniumでSelenium Managerにするのが良いかもしれません。【Selenium】ChromeDriver自動更新で楽する方法【Python】

chromeDriverのインストール先のディレクトリは正しいですか？ソースコードで定義していないところを見るに環境変数Pathに記載されているかと思いますが同じディレクトリにありますか？あと最新のドライバーはver127だと思いますが、ブラウザのバージョンは正しいですか

色々試してみました。ありがとうございました。無事解決しました。

同じ現象が出たので、調べて直してみました。
どなたかがコメントを付けているように、【Selenium】ChromeDriver自動更新で楽する方法【Python】の対処をすると、エラーメッセージが出ず、実行できました。

Selenium 4.6以上を使っている場合
BEFORE
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

service = ChromeService(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

AFTER
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()



教えていただきありがとうございました。無事解決しました！
